# MYSQL inserting rows with missing dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date, recursive-query

I have a table with two columns:

| name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| AA | 2021-06-01 |
| BB | 2021-06-02 |
| CC | 2021-05-28 |

I want to write a code to add rows with names and dates until today's(2021-06-03) date like this:

| name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| AA | 2021-06-01 |
| AA | 2021-06-02 |
| AA | 2021-06-03 |
| BB | 2021-06-02 |
| BB | 2021-06-03 |
| CC | 2021-05-28 |
| CC | 2021-05-29 |
| CC | 2021-05-30 |
| CC | 2021-05-31 |
| CC | 2021-06-01 |
| CC | 2021-06-02 |
| CC | 2021-06-03 |

I have not worked with recursive functions so not sure what is the best course of action here. Any help or pointers in the right direction will be appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: The version is 5.7.33.

Comment: This is much simpler in 8.0+. If you can update, consider doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For recent versions of MySQL, you can do...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;
CREATE TABLE my_table
(name CHAR(2) NOT NULL
,date DATE NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(name,date)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('AA','2021-06-01'),
('BB','2021-06-02'),
('CC','2021-05-28');

WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
(
  SELECT MIN(date) date FROM my_table 
   UNION ALL
  SELECT date + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
    FROM cte
   WHERE date + INTERVAL 1 DAY <= '2021-06-03'
)
SELECT x.name
     , cte.date
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN cte
    ON cte.date >= x.date
 ORDER 
    BY name
     , date


| name | date       |
| ---- | ---------- |
| AA   | 2021-06-01 |
| AA   | 2021-06-02 |
| AA   | 2021-06-03 |
| BB   | 2021-06-02 |
| BB   | 2021-06-03 |
| CC   | 2021-05-28 |
| CC   | 2021-05-29 |
| CC   | 2021-05-30 |
| CC   | 2021-05-31 |
| CC   | 2021-06-01 |
| CC   | 2021-06-02 |
| CC   | 2021-06-03 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wL3ZqXoTqdKftJCPA4um4j/1)
```

For older versions, you can use a uility table. For example, I have a table of integers (i) with values from 0 to 9...

```
SELECT y.name
     , x.date 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT MIN(date) + INTERVAL i DAY date FROM my_table,ints GROUP BY i HAVING date <= '2021-06-03' ) x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.date <= x.date 
 ORDER 
    BY name
     , date;
+------+------------+
| name | date       |
+------+------------+
| AA   | 2021-06-01 |
| AA   | 2021-06-02 |
| AA   | 2021-06-03 |
| BB   | 2021-06-02 |
| BB   | 2021-06-03 |
| CC   | 2021-05-28 |
| CC   | 2021-05-29 |
| CC   | 2021-05-30 |
| CC   | 2021-05-31 |
| CC   | 2021-06-01 |
| CC   | 2021-06-02 |
| CC   | 2021-06-03 |
+------+------------+
```

Comment: Hi, trying the code for lower versions and have an error. "SELECT MIN(date) + INTERVAL i DAY date FROM my_table,??ints?? GROUP BY i HAVING date <= '2021-06-03' )" what is ints in this line of code? I created an integer table called i from 0 to 9.

Answer (score 0):

You want to generate rows from the rows in your table to the date `'2021-06-03'`.  You can do this directly with a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select name, date
      from t
      union all
      select name, date + interval 1 day
      from cte
      where date < '2021-06-03'
     )
select *
from cte
order by name, date;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2a298a1cfb4c6bfca16be967d9a276a1) is a db<>fiddle.

You can read the recursive CTE as:

- Start with the row in the given table.
- Add one day to the date.
- Stop when the date is the end date.

Not only is this simpler than "generating all the dates" and then joining, but it should also be faster.

Comment: This would have been perfect if I was working on MySQL version 8.0+ which I can't change sadly.

Comment: @PriyaPatel . . . Your question is *tagged* "recursive-cte".  This uses a recursive CTE just as the question asks.

Comment: Yes sorry about that, I found out later on that recursive cte is not supported in my version.